# Can "between" be used with "which"?

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns

We can say , for example:

> The house, **in which** my sister lives, was located in the countryside"

But could I make a sentence like:

> The house and the tree, **between which** I parked my car, were the same color."

Is there a usage of "between" with the relative pronoun "which"? If there isn't, how can I express it while keeping the same meaning and form?

Comment: It's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is technically just fine, and in fact is actually the grammatically correct way to say that.  You will definitely not be marked down on a test or an academic paper for using `between which` in that way (in fact you might be applauded).

However, the unfortunate truth is that there are cases where "grammatically correct" and "commonly used" are not the same thing.  This is one of those cases.

Despite being correct, saying `between which I parked my car` will likely sound awkward to most English speakers.  Instead, most native speakers would probably say `which I parked my car between`, *even though this is not actually grammatically correct.*

So, if you're looking to be correct (for example, in an academic/professional setting) the way you have phrased it is actually the right way to go.  If you're speaking more informally, using the incorrect but more common `which ... between` form will likely sound more natural to most people.

Comment: I would advise against using `which I parked my car between` and stick with the OP's original construction `between which I parked my car`.

Comment: Mowzer, I would advise against picking either one without knowing the context...

Answer (score 0):

> *The house and the tree, between which I parked my car, were the same colour.*

Your sentence is fine. It works.

As a matter of practice, I personally prefer to stick to one idea per sentence. So here is an alternate construction for your consideration.

> **The house and the tree were the same color. I parked my car between them.**
>
> or
>
> **I parked my car between the house and tree. They were the same color.**

However, this is by no means required. It's really just a matter of my personal writing style and taste.